# GroupBy and OrderBy using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I get data from my db using linq. I would like to use a GroupBy and an OrderBy on the same Request.

I actually have this code which doesn't work:

```
var mydata = _db.table1
    .Join(_db.table2, h => h.col1, t => t.col2, 
        (h, t) => new ActivatedScripts() 
        {
            col1 = h.col1, col2 = h.col2, col3 = (t.col3 == "Y"), col4 = "" 
        })
    .GroupBy(z => z.col1).OrderBy(s => s.....);
```

the `OrderBy(s => s...)` suggest me all the LINQ method and a famous KEY which doesn't match any column in my code.

EDIT :

I follow the official tutorial to sort my table (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

When I groupBy then sort (I tried to sort then groupby) I have an exception :

[image]

Comment: you've grouped your data by `col1`, so you can ONLY sort by `col1` OR by any aggregate function. Think about this.

Comment: for instance, `s => s.Key.col1` or `s => s.Sum(item => item.col2)`

Comment: You tagged this question with several different query providers.  Which are you *actually* using?

Comment: I use EF 6 with LINQ requests

Answer (score 3):

The `GroupBy` method returns a collection of groups. You can easily sort on the `col1` column as that is the `Key` property of each group:

```
.OrderBy(s => s.Key)
```

If you want to sort on anything else, you have to get that value from the items in the group. If you for example know that a value is the same for all items in each group, you can get the value from the first item in the group:

```
.OrderBy(s => s.First().col2)
```

You can also use aggregates to calculate values using all the items in the group, for example sorting on the sum of the values:

```
.OrderBy(s => s.Sum(x => x.col2))
```

Comment: If all of the values should be the same then he should be grouping on that value as well, if they're not, then the results are effectively indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

You can always order first and then group the ordered data:

```
.Join(...).OrderBy(x => x.col1).GroupBy(x => x.col2)
```